# React: How can I position the loading component so it is in the center of the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is the code and demo :

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-silence-7cv3l

https://7cv3l.csb.app/

I used `react-image-enlarger` component for zooming images like Medium. And it has a API, `renderLoading` to render a loading component when the enlarged image is downloading. So I imported `react-loading` for the loading component.

The relevant code snippet:

```
<div style={{ margin: "0.25rem" }}>
      <Image
        style={{ width: "200px", height: "auto" }}
        zoomed={zoomed}
        src={src}
        enlargedSrc={{}}
        onClick={() => setZoomed(true)}
        onRequestClose={() => setZoomed(false)}
        renderLoading={<ReactLoading type={"cylon"} color="black" />}
      />
    </div>
```

And now the loading animation appears below the image.

[image]

However I want to the loading animation to **be at the center of the image and there should be a filter applied against the image** to make it darker(maybe `brightness(0.7);`)

I think this is not a trivial job since every image has its own height and width and I'm not really good at CSS so any help is appreciated.

Comment: flex is supposed to do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css code to set the position of loader on center of each image it will works.

```
img.EnlargedImage__Image + div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
img.EnlargedImage__Image + div svg {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Also how can I make the image to be darker when the loading animation is showing?

Comment: @Joji as per your comment i was make change in my answer it will give you overlay on image while loading animation is showing.

Comment: Hi,   Could you also please add the a transition effect to the change of background-color?

Comment: the background-color is given to the div and that was not show in structure at page load it appends on click of image. we can give transition effect to the pre-define div only not to on the div which appends at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Add `classname="loader"` prop to your loader component. shown below Add this `CSS` in your file

**Edit:** added `transition: all 0.5s;` to `.loader`

```
renderLoading={<ReactLoading type={"cylon"} color="black" className="loader"/>

.EnlargedImage__container .loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    transition: all 0.5s;
```

}

```
.EnlargedImage__container .loader svg {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! It works! However at the same time how can I make the image to be darker when the loading animation is showing?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the update! Could you also please add the  a transition effect to the change of `background-color`? I tried it myself but couldn't figure out where to add.

Comment: @Joji I have updated my answer please check. thanks